# Javascript variables to php

Tags: javascript, php

I am working with javascript and php, and I am trying to pass javascript variables from an html file to an php file. I already try a lot of ways using `window.location.href` and `$_GET` and `$_POST`. I dont know what I am doing wrong, or if his something missing, any suggestions to how pass javascript variables to php?

html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="zepto.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function values() {          
        var wind = 300;
        var rain = 0;
        var speed = 35;

        window.location.href = "getData.php?s1=" + wind + "&s2=" + rain + "&s3=" + speed;          
    }
</script>
```

php file:

```
<?php
$sensors=new Sensor();

if (isset($_GET['s1']) && isset($_GET['s2']) && isset($_GET['s3'])) {

$wind = $_GET['s1'];
$rain = $_GET['s2'];
$speed = $_GET['s3'];

$sensors->create();
}

?>
```

Comment: I would recommend an AJAX request. Is it acceptable to use jQuery for this solution or can you only use Javascript?

Comment: What results are you getting? ur code worked for me

Comment: how do we know your class isn't failing neither. Not enough code here. Check for errors via PHP and look at your console. I also don't see you echoing anything. How are you calling that `values()` function? Probably why it's failing here, not calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your (JS) code isn't working because you never called the `values()` function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function values() {          
        var wind = 300;
        var rain = 0;
        var speed = 35;

        window.location.href = "getData.php?s1=" + wind + "&s2=" + rain + "&s3=" + speed;          
    }

values(); // Add this to fire up the function

</script>
```

This assuming that the rest of your code checks out for the class you're using.

You will also have to echo out those values in your PHP:

```
echo $wind = $_GET['s1'];
echo $rain = $_GET['s2'];
echo $speed = $_GET['s3'];
```